# If we cool gates in semiconductor transistors, can we reduce the overall energy of electrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

I was reading about Moore's law and was a bit confused about why semiconductors aren't cooled down. If we have an issue with quantum tunnelling, cooling the wafer could reduce the energy level of the electrons. We might need more sensitive materials to achieve similar voltage differences but I'm still curious about why this is not a good idea.

Thanks!

Comment: It is, it's just not so straight forward to do effectively at that scale.  Cooling mechanisms tend to be macroscopic, after all it takes energy to move the electrons.

Comment: Hypothetically, if we could cool them at the scale or if we could cool certain parts of the transistor. If we fabricated the die with channels for cooling fluid or any other working fluid, could this problem become more feasible?

Comment: With a relatively high thermal conductivity of 149 W·m−1·K−1, silicon conducts heat well. The problem is more getting the heat away from the silicon than across it.

Comment: Just read some journal articles. Usually the first time something new is done, like a faster transistor, or a brighter laser diode, it's done with the device submerged in liquid nitrogen. Getting stuff to run at room temperature and higher is a big engineering challenge that's done to keep costs down for the end user.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that reducing the temperature will drive down leakage current, and this would lower energy waste and also increase signal fidelity.

To some extent this is already done, though not in the way you imagine. All transistors dissipate energy,  so they tend to heat up. Usually heat sinks, fans,  water cooling, etc. work to bring the chip back to room temperature. Otherwise the chip would burn itself out very quickly.

What is not done is to cool to significantly lower than room temperature. This is because cooling requires a lot of energy and is not very efficient,  so it would make the computer chip even more energy inefficient overall. However, for some large scale things like servers and supercomputers, cooling is not uncommon because of the sheer scale of things